# Why my isPrime function returns True for 187?

Tags: python, function

I'm fairly new to coding so forgive me my lack of knowledge.
I am trying to write a function which checks if a number is prime, yet for some non-prime numbers I test it returns as True. Can anyone explain why that may be so I can find a way to fix it?

```
def isPrime(num):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range (2,num):
            if num % i == 0:
                return False
            else:
                return True


isPrime(113)
Out[50]: True

isPrime(187)
Out[51]: True
```

Comment: You should indent code with 4 spaces. That will make it show as code on your post, which makes it more readable!

Comment: This function tests whether a number is odd or even. Go through it line for line and you should see why.

Comment: Check out: https://linoxide.com/how-tos/programs/basic-python-if-while/

Comment: Why all the downvotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code almost works, it could for example be like this:

```
def isPrime(num):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range (2,num):
            if num % i == 0:
                return False
    return True
```

Comment: So why would 187 be returning True for me in my original code? Is it because it is still in the loop and if/else statement?

Comment: @CarlWolter your original code will check first that the number is not divisible by 2 and then immediately return True.

Comment: @CarlWolter because the code you provided will always exit on the first loop iteration since you're returning whether or not `num % i == 0`. Since the first value is 2, and `187 % 2 != 1`, your code returns true. Like @tkausl was saying your code accidentally acted as a function to test if a number was odd or even.

Comment: Going up to num adds extra complexity to the function. You can go up to sqrt(num) to reduce the time by half since is something is prime it won't have a square root.

Comment: @EdekiOkoh I belive he only needs to check until `int(sqrt(num)) + 1`.

Comment: Well it would be int(sqrt(num)) + 1 if it is odd, and int(sqrt(num)) if it is even